# Updating old function to Jquery 1.11.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following bit of code validates a username by communicating with check.php (which echos 'OK' if there are no errors) and changing the field css class. **It runs properly in jQuery 1.2.6 and I have tried numerous noConflict() workarounds to get 1.11.3 to run alongside it, but to no avail.** I'm a jQuery (and all-around) programming newbie, but I believe the issue is in a depreciated function in this code... perhaps in $.ajax bit.

Any advice on how to update this for 1.11.3 (or better ideas) would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#username").change(function() {

    var usr = $("#username").val();

    if (usr.length >= 4) {
      $("#username").addClass("object_thinking");
      $("#status").html('');

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check.php",
        data: "username=" + usr,
        success: function(msg) {

          $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {

            if (msg == 'OK') {
              $("#username").removeClass('object_thinking');
              $("#username").removeClass('object_error');
              $("#username").addClass("object_ok");
              $("#status").html('');
            } else {
              $("#username").removeClass('object_ok');
              $("#username").addClass("object_error");
              $("#status").html("<font color='red'>" + 'Username already in
use</font>');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#status").html('<font color="red">The username should have at least  
<strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
      $("#username").removeClass('object_ok');
      $("#username").addClass("object_error");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please indent your code to make it more readable. And then, what _does_ it do with jQuery 1.11.3? Does it not run at all, does it give unexpected results, …? And what does your browser’s error console say?

Comment: Using <font> is bad.

Comment: Using ajaxComplete in the success seems wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. 
The function is to check if a username is registered and display a different css class per situation: thinking/OK/No good 
Check.php is just a simple db query to find if a username exists, if it does, it echoes 'OK' -> the code above reads that, and acts accordingly. This function works fine in 1.2.6, but not 1.11.3, and its starting to bother me ;(

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this at all, but I know the syntax is valid... Just cleaned your functions up a bit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $username = $('#username');
  var $status = $('#status');

  $username.change(function() {

    var usr = $username.val();

    if ( usr.length >= 4 ) {

      $username.addClass('object_thinking');
      $status.empty();

      $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: 'username=' + usr
      })
      .done(function(msg) {

        if ( msg === 'OK' ) {

          $username.removeClass('object_thinking').removeClass('object_error').addClass('object_ok');
          $status.empty();

        } else {

          $username.removeClass('object_ok').addClass('object_error');
          $status.html('<span style="color: red;">Username already in
use</span>');

        }

      });

    } else {

      $status.html('<span style="color: red;">The username should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</span>');
      $username.removeClass('object_ok').addClass('object_error');

    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you all for the advice and the rewrite!
Sadly, that produced the same results (1.2.6 OK, 1.11.3 not).
The function is to check my db if a username is taken. It talks to check.php to find it in the db. 
Here is the check.php file: 
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
 $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db") or die("Error ". mysqli_error($db)); 
 $username = $_POST['username'];  
    $u_check = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'"; 
 $result = mysqli_query($db,$u_check); 
 $user_check = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
 if ($user_check == 0)
 {
 echo 'OK';
 } 
}

Comment: I know this may be obvious, but make sure the check.php url is correct. If this JS file is in the same directory as the PHP file, then you're fine. Try running async: false in the $.ajax bit...

Answer (score 0):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Finally pulled through. I wasn't adding $j to all the parts of the function. 
Thanks so much for you help and advice guys!

Comment: Glad you got that sorted!